# ecxel: add a non continuous cell to an array

Tags: arrays, excel, rank

I'm calculating the percentile of a value in an array.

```
=PERCENTRANK.INC(O14:O10001,O6)
```

The problem is that cell O6 is the smallest number in the series. This returns #N/A.

Is there an easy way to add it to the array, such that the above returns 0%

Thanks in advance,

Tikhon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the formula to include O6 in the array in parenthesis as below

```
=PERCENTRANK.INC(($O$14:$O$10001,$O$6),O6)
```

[image]